# using yii with memcache, error when one of two server fails

Tags: php, yii, memcached

i have a problem with yii and storing data in memcache. For my application i use system.caching.CMemCache and the following config:

```
'servers' => array(
    'server1' => array('host' => 'localhost', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 50),
    'server2' => array('host' => '192.168.0.2', 'port' => 11211, 'weight' => 50)
),
```

if memcache on both systems is running, everything is ok and the values get spread up on the servers. but if one server fails (or if i stop the memcache manually) the application throw errors like

```
MemcachePool::get(): Server 192.168.0.2 (tcp 11211, udp 0) failed with: Connection refused (111)
```

this isn't really nice, i thought if one server failed yii would choose another server for reading and writing or at least produce some cache misses and do not throw an exeption :(

is this normal or are there some configuration issues?

Comment: are u using `memcached` or `memcache` ? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CMemCache#useMemcached-detail .Are u able to connect with these servers from command line ?

Answer (score 2):

I think its normal you are seeing those messages as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15779167/ignoring-server-down-error-message-when-using-yii-cmemcache), given you are using `memcache` extension

And also read this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9405433/sessions-failover-with-php-memcache-against-memcached).

There are two version of extension for php one is `memcache` while the other is `memcached`. You can install each of them on ubuntu box like :

```
 sudo apt-get install php5-memcache
  and 
 sudo apt-get install php5-memcached
```

`Memecached` extension handles `failover` situations ,as I read from the above links and confirm by testing following settings in yii

```
'cache'=>array(
            'class'=>'CMemCache',
            'useMemcached'=>true,
            'servers'=>array(
                array(
                    'host'=>'localhost',
                    'port'=>11211,
                    'weight'=>60,
                ),
                array(
                    'host'=>'192.168.33.31',
                    'port'=>11211,
                    'weight'=>30,
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Install the `memcached` extension for php as described above and add `'useMemcached'=>true,` setting to cache configs.As I test on my localhost, it handles the failover situation, but the page response time drops significantly.

Hope this will be helpful.

Comment: hi sakhunzai, thanks for your answer, maybe it really is because i use memcache and not memcached. after some refresh or some time the message do not show again and the application use another memcache-server.  but in my case i just saw i am not able to use memcache, because if i use 3 server and one server dies, a lot of cache keys from the other 2 server get rewritten and because of performance issues that's not a possibility for me

Answer (score 0):

Is this variable true?

http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.ini.php#ini.memcache.allow-failover

Otherwise this link can also be useful:

[Memcache : Confusions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11778495/memcache-confusions)

(Probably this is only a notice.)