# Two memcache server on local machine

Tags: php, caching, yii2, memcached, multiserver

I am trying to create a demo on MemCache with multiple servers. I have installed WAMP and XAMPP on my local machine. Wamp can be accessed by `localhost` and XAMPP can be accessed by `localhost:7980`.

I have installed Memcache on both servers (correct versions are installed). On both server's `phpinfo()` shows memcache is installed. My one memcache server port is `11211` and second memcache server port is `11212`. I am using `yii2` and my configuration is as below.

```
'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\MemCache',
        'servers' => [
            [
                'host' => 'localhost',
                'port' => 11211,
                'weight' => 60,
            ],
            [
                'host' => 'localhost:7980',
                'port' => 11212,
                'weight' => 60,
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

I am getting below error

`MemcachePool::get(): Server localhost:7980 (tcp 11212, udp 0) failed with: Malformed VALUE header (0)`

Please guide me where I'm going wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What version of Memcached does your installation have? Can you connect to two servers if they're not on the same machine?

Comment: @Scuzzy its `Version 3.0.8` on both servers.

Comment: found a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19299259/using-yii-with-memcache-error-when-one-of-two-server-fails still trying to find anything else.

Comment: @Scuzzy `useMemcached` is set to `false` in my configuration

Comment: Are you aware that whilst you may have a _Memcache_ server there are two different PHP libraries to connect to Memcache? Lib [Memcache](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) and [Memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcached.php). Might be worth trying the alternative one to what you're using.

Comment: @Scuzzy It works when I use the server of port `11211` but not with the `11212`

Comment: Wait, your "host" syntax has `:7980` in it, is this unessesary since you then specify `11212` as the port?

Comment: @Scuzzy If I remove the port `:7980` then I am getting this error: 
`MemcachePool::get(): Server localhost (tcp 11212, udp 0) failed with: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
(10060)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is fixed by starting the server on a different port. I used below command and it worked.
`memcached.exe install -p 11212`